# is there any way to setcookies to WebBrowser control in the windows phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, setcookie

Is there any way to set cookies to WebBrowser control in the Windows Phone 8 app? Please suggest any solution or workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11092692/revisions ?
Let me know if it worked for you .. thx